# Running NDepend analysis through command line?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ndepend

Is there a way to use the NDepend console executable to run a type of analysis on a C# project/solution and produce output of the analysis? The only information I can find on the NDepend console relates to existing NDepend projects.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your NDepend project from the `.sln / .csproj` files. For that you need to write your own program based on NDepend.API and then run the analysis, through NDepend.API as well.

Source code for that is available [here](http://www.ndepend.com/api/webframe.html?NDepend.API_gettingstarted.html).